# IIS CORS configuration for one file

Tags: iis, cors

Microsoft claims CORS can be enabled using the CORS module of IIS on a single file (point #1 see reference).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/cors-module/cors-module-configuration-reference

How can this be done?  I don't see anything restricting the rules by site or file.
Does anyone know where the DTD for this module is?  I can figure it out if I have the specification.

Comment: Learn how to use location tags, https://serverfault.com/questions/811666/iis-how-to-allow-a-single-file-as-browsable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Lex li!

An example of how to do this is below:

```
<location path="myFile.json">
    <system.webServer>
        <cors enabled="true">
           <add origin="https://*.myDomain.com"> 
               <allowHeaders allowAllRequestedHeaders="true">
               </allowHeaders>
           </add>
       </cors>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Obviously you can add other CORS attributes in the middle as you see fit, but this solves the "location" part of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just would like provide a GUI way to set cors,
You could go to IIS manager ->site node->content view->select the file you want to set CORS->switch back to feature view.

[image]

Now you will see the file in your site node.You can go to configuration manager and set CORS module via web.config.

[image]
[image]